# set the quality of svg render

Tags: google-chrome, css, svg, render, scale

Usually the browser renders the svg images properly but in chrome the browser doesn't detects the css3 scale and return a poor image. This must be because css scale is a new technology... Is there any way to select the render quality?

Sorry for my english, I'm studying it!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of workarounds for this, none as easy as setting a render quality directive, I'm afraid. The most straightforward workaround would be inserting the actual SVG instead of using it inside an img tag.

Your html would look like...

```
<svg>
  ...
</svg>
```

And your css would look like...

```
svg {
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EgsGe/